# how to bring datepicker's dropdown panel to top in Vue.js?

Tags: html, css, web, vue.js

im writing a web page using IView components by Vue.js. however, when i nest a datepicker component inside a card component, datepicker's dropdown menu doesn't work here. it seems that the dropdown panel has been hidden beneath the card. how can i bring it back to the top? thanks.
here's part of my code:

```
    <card class="card">
  <p slot="title">线下订单统计</p>
  <Col>
    <Col span="3" class="offlineOrderSplitter">
      <div class="offlineOrderSplitterDiv">
        <p>本月订单总数</p>
      </div>
      <div class="offlineOrderSplitterDiv">
        <p>本周订单总数</p>
      </div>
    </Col>
    <Col span="20">
      <div>
        <span style="padding-left:10px">近一周订单统计</span>
        <div style="float:right">
          <span>今日</span>
          <span>本周</span>
          <span>本月</span>
          <span>
            <DatePicker type="daterange" placement="bottom-end" placeholder="选择日期" style="width: 200px"></DatePicker>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Col>
  </Col>
</card>
```

here's my screenshots of it. when the datepicker's dropdown panel is shown at bottom, it works because it doesn't reach outside of card. But when the popup panel is at top, the problem arises.
[image]
[image]

also I want to point out that I have tried z-index with highest value, and it simply doesn't work.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet your card component has `overflow: hidden;` set so when you try to render it above it's overflowing the container and being hidden by that CSS rule.

Comment: CSS = position:relative      on datepicker ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by setting property `transfer` to `true` of datapicker.